# How do I pass multiple parameters to a class with __new__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, oop

I'm trying to understand __new__ and I'm fairly new to OOP python. I have this code...

```py
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import logging
import typing as T


class MaxLength(str):
    def __new__(cls, field: str):

        # how do i pass this dynamically in the PCW obj
        maximum = 4

        if len(field) > maximum:
            raise ValueError('invalid length of fields at: ' + field)
        return super().__new__(cls, field)


class PCW(T.NamedTuple):
    length_checker: MaxLength

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: dict):

        return cls(**{key: type_(row[key]) for key, type_ in cls._field_types.items()})


def validate_csv(reader: DictReader) -> bool:
    for row in reader:
        try:
            PCW.from_row(row)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('type: {} msg: {}'.format(type(e), e))
            return False
    return True


input_file = validate_csv(csv.DictReader(open("test.csv")))
```

This works but I want to be able to pass `maximum` in as an argument so as this will change. ie:

```py
class PCW(T.NamedTuple):
    length_checker: MaxLength(maximum=4)
    ...


input_file = validate_csv(csv.DictReader(open("test.csv")))
```

I think I have gone down the rabbit hole. Is this possible or what am I overlooking/misunderstanding?

Comment: With `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: could you post some code showing me?

Comment: Where do you actually use `length_checker`?

Comment: length_checker is a field in the CSV file - sorry should have said that in the original Q

Comment: How are the field in the CSV file and the class attribute related?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sample csv file that could be used for testing — or added other code that could be used to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the [`object.__init_subclass__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) classmethod that was added in Python 3.6. Making use of it requires subclassing your `MaxLength` subclass.

Here's what I mean:

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import logging
import typing as T


class MaxLength(str):
    maximum = 8

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        maximum = kwargs.pop('maximum', cls.maximum)
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.maximum = maximum

    def __new__(cls, field: str):
        if len(field) > cls.maximum:
            raise ValueError('invalid length of fields at: ' + field)
        return super().__new__(cls, field)


class PCW(T.NamedTuple):
#    class PCWMaxLength(MaxLength):
    class PCWMaxLength(MaxLength, maximum=4): # Override default maximum.
        pass

    length_checker: PCWMaxLength

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: dict):
        return cls(**{key: type_(row[key]) for key, type_ in cls._field_types.items()})

    # Display value assigned to nested class' constant.
    print(f'PCWMaxLength.maximum: {PCWMaxLength.maximum}') # -> PCWMaxLength.maximum: 4


def validate_csv(reader: DictReader) -> bool:
    for row in reader:
        try:
            PCW.from_row(row)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('type: {} msg: {}'.format(type(e), e))
            return False
    return True
```

Otherwise, I think you will need to do some actual metaclass programming…

Comment: Thank you martin for putting me out of my misery, this is working - plus i learnt something new :D

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a default argument:

```py
class MaxLength(str):
    def __new__(cls, field: str, maximum: int=4):

        if len(field) > maximum:
            raise ValueError('invalid length of fields at: ' + field)
        return super().__new__(cls, field)
```

Comment: how would i dynamically set the int elsewhere though?

Comment: @alex you can call it in just the same way you did before, optionally adding a third argument. ie: `MaxLength("asdf")` would have `maximum=4` whereas `MaxLength("asdf", 5)` would have `maximum=5`

Comment: Hmm, I get ERROR:root:type: <class 'TypeError'> msg: 'ForwardRef' object is not callable

Comment: Without the CSV or the full traceback, I don't know how that error could be produced :/